# Rabbit - Error: mnesia_unexpectedly_running

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra

I am trying to cluster rabbit using chef

Here is my error.  I shutdown all of rabbit on the second node.

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@ip-10-158-xxx-xxx

Error: mnesia_unexpectedly_running
```

So..what is the deal?  I tried this from http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2010/05/rabbitmq-clustering-in-ubuntu.html which is to remove  /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia.  No go.  And on what server doen it not be be running?  All?

Thanks

Answer (score 48):

Make sure you call `sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app` before issuing the cluster command. That seemed to be the problem for me.

Then make sure you call `sudo rabbitmqctl start_app` to begin it again :)

Comment: Worth noting that I had to do both steps separately. Using `sudo rabbitmqctl force_reset` did not work.

Answer (score 5):

To call out a **very** important piece of @Itai Ganot's comment that's not immediately intuitive: you need to run `rabbitmqctl stop_app` on all nodes but one. If you run `rabbitmqctl stop_app` on all nodes, you will get a different message: `Error: mnesia_not_running`.

In short:

- `Error: mnesia_unexpectedly_running` means "you need to run `rabbitmqctl stop_app` on this node
- `Error: mnesia_not_running` means "you need to run `rabbitmqctl start_app` on the node you're trying to cluster with"

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy the cookie from the node you trying to connect

Let us use an example with 2 nodes: rabbit@node1 and rabbit@node2

1. Go to `rabbit@node1` and copy the cookie from cat `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`
2. Go to `rabbit@node2` remove the current cookie and paste the new one.
3. Execute the following commands on the same node

   ```
   /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop_app
   /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl reset
   /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@node1
   ```

That should do it.

The same procedure is documented [here](http://pearlin.info/?p=1672)

Comment: For Windows (In elevated command prompt):
1. rabbitmqctl stop_app
2. rabbitmqctl reset
3. rabbitmqctl start_app

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached | DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"*.

Answer (score 2):

I also received the same error while trying to create a cluster of two rabbitmq servers.

As far as I know, the real process to create a cluster is a little bit different than the ones described in the other answers but is the one which eventually worked for me:

After you have two or more nodes running rabbitmq-server, choose one server and that's the one you don't touch - let's call it rabbitmaster, in all the other nodes, follow these steps:

```
1. Make sure the rabbitmq-server is not running.
2. # su - rabbitmq
3. $ rabbitmq-server -detached
4. $ rabbitmqctl cluster_status
5. $ rabbitmqctl stop_app
6. $ rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbitmaster
7. $ rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Now you can run `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` and see both the node you just configured and the rabbitmq master.

More information can be found in [RabbitMQ Official site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html).

Answer (score 0):

I dont like to answer my own qustion but clustering rabbin usig chef was a true pain.  Issue with rabbit was resolved by not using the -N option with bootstrapping.  Rabbit does not like the hostname to be changed.

So..following the docs on the rabbit site for clustering worked as expected.  If you use the -N option with chef...major issues will arise.

Comment: Or edit the rabbitmq slaves' /etc/hosts file with entries for the nodes and assign an elastic IP to all members. Changing the hostname, or using the -N option, isn't really the issue here, you just need to work around it or override the cookbook defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This means the app on the current node you are trying to link is running. Stop the app on the current node before joining it to the master node.

`sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app`
`rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@ip-10-158-xxx-xxx`. then
`rabbitmqctl start_app`.

Also make sure the app on the master node is running. Otherwise you'll get `Error: mnesia_not_running` error.